# Merge row data of python data frame based on some condition

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a python data from as below. in every row I have some similar "string", in every round of similar string, I want to merge the first one with the first, then the first one with second one, then the first one with the third, can anyone help me please?

```
   row   label
1  x     a
2  x     bb
3  x     cc
4  x     rr
5  x     uu
6  y     ff
7  y     bb
8  y     nn
```

I want :

```
0  x  a
1  x  abb
2  x  acc
3  x  arr
4  x  auu
5  y  ff 
6  y  ffbb
7  y  ffnn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- your transform is append first item in series to all other item in series
- this is use of `transform()` with a `lambda` that does a list comprehension

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""   row   label
1  x     a
2  x     bb
3  x     cc
4  x     rr
5  x     uu
6  y     ff
7  y     bb
8  y     nn"""), sep="\s+")

df["label"] = df.groupby("row")["label"].transform(lambda s: [s.values[0]+x if i>0 else x for i,x in enumerate(s)])
```

|  | row | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | a |
| 2 | x | abb |
| 3 | x | acc |
| 4 | x | arr |
| 5 | x | auu |
| 6 | y | ff |
| 7 | y | ffbb |
| 8 | y | ffnn |